# How do I access phpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, apache, http, phpmyadmin

I installed phpMyAdmin on my computer. I used Apache as my http server. However, every time I go to `http://localhost/phpMyAdmin/`, this screen appears:

[image]

How do I make it so that this login screen appears instead:

[image]

Comment: have you tried the documentation of the what ever client you installed?

Comment: See.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7977774/1305169

Comment: Does this answer your question? [index.php not loading by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384423/index-php-not-loading-by-default)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be better off to install an integrated suite, such as:

[XAMPP - Linux/Windows/Apple](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html)
* store web pages in htdocs

[WAMP  - Windows](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

[MAMP  - Apple](http://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/)

Then, just going to the address `localhost` will give you a menu, with all components (apache, phpmyadmin, tomcat, etc etc)

They are all free, so why not?

Answer (score 1):

Add this

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

to `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` (or wherever your `apache.conf` or `httpd.conf` or whatever is).

If you happen to be running on Windows, look for the Apache webserver directory.

**XAMPP Users**: If you have installed it as a service, **changes to configuration files seem to take effect only when you restart the service through the Services panel** and not via the XAMPP control panel.

Comment: I can't seem to find the directory named "etc". Is that in the Apache directory? the phpMyAdmin directory? :(

Comment: Waaaaait, are you running windows?

Comment: Yeah, I'm running windows. Why?

Comment: Good luck in all your future endeavors.

Answer (score 0):

Use `http://localhost/phpMyAdmin/index.php`

or

Check your host config, check the `DirectoryIndex` param.

Answer (score 0):

I found that when I entered root in the username and left the password blank I got in

Comment: The given screenshot does not show anything to enter a user name

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your apache2 config file to include PHPmyadmin.

Do this:
`gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

OR `nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Add this to the end of your config file:

`Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`

Save then restart Apache:

`/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`