# Change default page Apache2 Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

When I go to my website an index of all the files shows up, when I choose a specific page the html isn't able to access the images in a file.  How can I make Apache2 automatically launch /var/www/home.html instead of /var/www?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use DirectoryIndex directive in vitual host context.

From [apache website](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex)

> The DirectoryIndex directive sets the list of resources to look for,
>   when the client requests an index of the directory by specifying a /
>   at the end of the directory name.

Here's the example:

```
<virtualhost *:80>

  ServerName  domain.com
  ServerAlias www.domain.com

  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex home.html index.html
  DocumentRoot /var/www

</virtualhost>
```

Comment: above is directory specific scope configuration. for apache environment scope configuration. use instruction below url and the changes are made in dir.conf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384423/index-php-not-loading-by-default

Comment: Perfect Answer. If you are using Wordpress only add DirectoryIndex index.php and restart apache

Answer (score 3):

In Apache2, specifying `DirectoryIndex` directive inside `virtualhost` tag of `sites-available/default` configuration file didn't work for me. Instead, placing `DirectoryIndex` directive inside `Directory` tag of `apache2.conf` file as mentioned in http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex did exactly what we want.