# apache not returning index.php as default

Tags: apache, lamp, digital-ocean, directoryindex

I recently made a DigitalOcean droplet with LAMP pre-installed.
Went and uploaded my website (including index.php) to /var/www

Apache just returns the It Works! page,
I have to manually add /index.php to my url

Things I have tried:

1. Made an .htaccess file containing "DirectoryIndex index.php"
2. Adding `DirectoryIndex index.php` to apache2.conf
3. Set index.php first in dir.conf
4. Making an index.html, didn't show that either.

EDIT:
 here's my apache2.conf file: http://pastebin.com/BMgiNdiD

Comment: whats in your apache2.conf? what directory has been set? Also you have set index.PHP to the directory index so a .html page will not override the php index page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [index.php not loading by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384423/index-php-not-loading-by-default)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing following configuration:

```
#
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.asp index.shtml index.html index.htm \
               default.php default.pl default.cgi default.asp default.shtml default.html \
               default.htm home.php home.pl home.cgi home.asp home.shtml home.html home.htm
</IfModule>
```