# http://localhost/admin/ route not working but works with http://localhost/admin/index.html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Hi Everyone I am working on an AngularJS project.

My project works fine on a route like: `http://localhost/`

But I have an admin panel like this: `//localhost/admin/`

So when I open this it's not working 
but when I put a complete URL like this: `localhost/admin/index.html#` 
then it works.

Project Structure is:
[Please Have A look on Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQCkp.png)

Comment: Need more info to help you. Add project structure etc

Comment: your webserver is probably not configured to serve a default document

Comment: Hello I have add image of project Structure

Comment: looks like a apache config problem and definitly not javascript angularjs or any other js problem. please take a look in your server config first if index.html is prefrered to start as index file on subdirs too

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the website in IIS you need to set Default Documents or check if it is set. I had the same issue a while ago and found the not all default were set.

[image]

Comment: website host in digital ocean

Comment: please have a look on project structure image

Comment: I think the same concept still applies, I found this now looking for the same setting on apache (assuming digital ocean hosts using apache) http://stackoverflow.com/a/21389339/811006

Answer (score 0):

You can create different states as per your project. For ex: 
1. /login
2. /admin
3. /edit

and then you can mention configuration for each state with the html page you want to access. then you can use //localhost/admin and it will be referred by /admin state which you have created.

Code should be something like this

```
$stateProvider.state('admin',{
    url:'/admin',
    controller: 'AdminController',
    templateUrl:'admin/index.html',
    resolve: {
      loadMyFiles:function($ocLazyLoad) { // this can be used for lazy loading of files
        return $ocLazyLoad.load({
          name:'MYPROJECT',
          files:[
          'styles/admin.css'
          ]
        })
      }
    }
  })
```

Comment: this part of routing is should be add in route routing??? not in admin??

Comment: Its application level routing you can create different states for your application and route as per your requirement.