# Apache DirectoryIndex directive not working correctly with Ruby on Rails

Tags: apache, passenger, mod-alias, directoryindex

I have a site where Ruby on Rails is running at the root directory via Phusion Passenger.  Some Apache `Alias` directives serve static HTML directories.

If you request an exact URL of a file from one of the static directories, Apache returns it as expected.  However, there are a few cases where I'm not getting the expected behavior.  Consider the alias `Alias /functional /path/to/functional`, where the *functional* directory contains *index.php* and *hello.jpg*.

1. A request for https://example.com/functional/hello.jpg returns the JPEG file as expected.
2. A request for https://example.com/functional/index.php runs the PHP script and prints the resulting HTML document as expected.
3. A request for https://example.com/functional/ results in a 404 **in the Rails stack**.
4. A request for https://example.com/functional (without the trailing slash) also results in a 404 in the Rails stack.  Ideally this URL should return a 301 redirecting the user to http://example.com/functional/

If I add an *index.html* file into the *functional* directory (in addition to the *index.php* that is already there), paths #3 and #4 return that file as expected.

Here's the relevant parts from my Apache configuration file for Passenger:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /path/to/mod_passenger.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
    # ... passenger setup stuff omitted ...

    Listen 443
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName ...
        DocumentRoot /path/to/rails/public
        PassengerRuby /path/to/ruby
        <Directory /path/to/rails/public>
            Allow from all
            Options -MultiViews
        </Directory>

        #  ... ssl setup omitted ...

    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

And for the static directories:

```
Alias /functional /path/to/functional/
Alias /phpMyAdmin /path/to/phpMyAdmin/
# ... other aliases omitted ...

<Directory /path/to/functional>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride all
</Directory>
```

I've tried most of the answers in [index.php not loading by default](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2384423/1407170) to make *index.php* load, to no prevail.  I shouldn't even need to specify `DirectoryIndex index.php` since that line is already in *conf.d/php.conf*.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue where Rails is giving 404s on URLs which are supposed to be going elsewhere in the Apache stack?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing

```
<Directory /path/to/functional>
```

With

```
<Directory /functional>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The working solution was just a `RedirectMatch` statement in the virtualhost serving passenger as follows:

```
RedirectMatch  ^/path/to/functional(/)?$  /path/to/functional/index.php
```