# I got a laravel 5 blank page on Ubuntu / Plesk 11

Tags: ubuntu, laravel, plesk

I installed laravel 5 on Ubuntu ( last version ) with Plesk 11; I chmod the storage folder to 777, and till now I get a blank page.

I have installed mcrypt, but nothing happen, still a blank page display, also there is no source code inside it, strange...

Any help ?

Comment: Check your php, apache and mysql logs. If even you can't seem to find out what's going how can we find out?

Comment: Be sure to check the mounting point of your Apache's virtual host to Laravel `public` folder, so, `public_html/public`

Also, depending on which modules you enabled in Plesk, permission 777 would be rejected for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You can get more ideas from error_log of your apache which tells you exactly what goes wrong.

Most often it is related to permissions even though you say you changed it to 777. Other common issue is some of the Laravel dependencies missing from PHP.

Thirdly everything can be OK and your controller just does not return anything :)

Make sure that DocumentRoot goes to the public folder in the Laravel installation

Comment: Thanks Margus, this is my homeController :

Comment: I am glad that my comments helped. If all is good then you can accept the answer to close the question.

Comment: Sorry I cant' past here myController, but I think it is not from it, as it is working fine on local server. I think something missing on the server, on UBUNTU, but I don't know what exactly

Comment: Yes, this must be related to your environment. Server error_log must tell you what is the cause of Laravel not able to boot up. Make sure your DocumentRoot is public folder

Comment: How to do that Margus ? and how to check error_log ?

Comment: Check your server host, you must find error_log there. Use https://forge.laravel.com/ if there is trouble configuring your environment

Comment: I found that the website works fin with index.php, but not without it

Comment: In this case it is related to Apache config. Please add `DirectoryIndex index.php` into the public/.htaccess as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384423/index-php-not-loading-by-default

Comment: It is not work, this is my .htaccess 

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
DirectoryIndex index.php