# apache 2.4 error 404

Tags: php, apache

I just setup an Apache 2.4 & PHP 5.5.6 on ubuntu 12.04

When I call the page on a web browser ->  `mysite.com/index.php`, the pages shows normally and works, but if i call the page `mysite.com` (without the /index.php) i get the error `404`, the Apache does not load the index.php automatically.

I need to write this in navigation bar of the browser (the site have too an `index.html`). My virtual host of `mysite.conf` is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@mysite.org
DocumentRoot /home/alexbk/webs/mysite
ErrorLog /home/alexbk/webs/mysite/error.log
CustomLog /home/alexbk/webs/mysite/access.log combined

<Directory /home/alexbk/webs/mysite>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
Require all granted
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet -->
```

The folder does not have and htacess file. I try change the `apache2.conf`, but without luck.

Thanks for your help

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384423/index-php-not-loading-by-default

Answer (score 1):

The following should work for you:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mysite.org
    DocumentRoot /home/alexbk/webs/mysite
    ErrorLog /home/alexbk/webs/mysite/error.log
    CustomLog /home/alexbk/webs/mysite/access.log combined

    <Directory /home/alexbk/webs/mysite>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
        DirectoryIndex index.php
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet -->
```

**EDIT:**

If that doesn't work, go and edit /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf and change it from:

```
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml index.htm
</IfModule>
```

to:

```
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml index.htm
</IfModule>
```

As a side note, if you can't fine the dir.conf file within the mods-enabled folder then you need to run the following command:

```
sudo a2enmod dir
```

Comment: if i add the line Directory index , apache crash, with the follow error:  AH00526: Syntax error on line 10 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite.conf:
Invalid command 'DirectoryIndex', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: OK, remove that line from dentalvox.org.conf then. And instead go and edit /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf. In there you should have a line that says: DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml index.htm change that to say DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml index.htm

Comment: I forgot to say, if you can't find the dir.conf file then you need to run "sudo a2enmod dir"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to garry, for your help, my problem was that there are not a dir.load file in the mods-available folder then the command "sudo a2enmod dir" does not work, i need to create a dir.load file (with the line: LoadModule dir_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_dir.so); sure that the .so file exist and save into mods-available folder, then i can run "a2enmod dir" and works!!.