# MAMP vhosts not working

Tags: apache, mamp, vhosts

I am trying to add a vhost for a specific project located within my MAMP htdocs folder.

Steps I did:

Open `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/conf/apache/httpd.conf` and uncomment the `Include /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` line.

Open `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` and removed both demo vhosts, and added the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/arko/Sites/mysite"
    ServerName mysite
</VirtualHost>
```

Edit hosts file: `sudo vim /etc/hosts` and added this line:

```
127.0.0.1     mysite
```

My hosts file now looks like this:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost

# MAMP Virtual Hosts
127.0.0.1       mysite
```

Then I opened up my MAMP and restarted the servers (stop servers, then started servers).

Whenever I go to `http://mysite/` I just get the contents of `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs` (a ugly list of all my folders in there, since I have no index file in my `htdocs` folder.

So it seems like it is ignoring my vhost, and just using my hosts file to route `http://mysite/` to `127.0.0.1` (localhost)

---

### Update

When I go to http://mysite/ I get this error in my apache error log:

```
[Wed Mar 16 11:04:39 2016] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/.DS_Store
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this. I think apatch is hosting the .DS_STORE file.

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384423/index-php-not-loading-by-default)