# My website not show without write index.php after the domain name in phpbb

Tags: php, mybb

**I want to install MYBB latest version in my online server.**

I have installed mybb forum but when i write domain name on the address bar then its show directory list.
But when i write domain name + index.php then its show the MYbb forum main page.
i have properly installed mybb but without write index.php its not work otherwise show directory list 
.
kindly guide me?

*below i show when i write domain name + index.php then its work* 
otherwise its show directory list.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPbz0.png)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384423/index-php-not-loading-by-default 

You need to add index.php as "an index file" on the webserver. Different webservers do it differently. For apache you use 'DirectoryIndex' directive, for nginx you specify 'index' in the server definition etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about application configuration, not programming. StackOverflow is intended as a programming Q&A. For questions like this about how to use or configure specific software packages, you should probably start with the support tools and communities for the program you're trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your .htaccess file to include

```
IndexIgnore *
```

That should stop the directories from appearing.

EDIT: phpbb? mybb?  why did I even bother...