# new moodle shows default apache page

Tags: moodle

I just installed ubuntu 16.04 server, and moodle 3.1. I suspect this is a mistake: I copied everything of moodle into /var/www/html, instead of into /var/www. My suspect comes from the fact that http://siteaddress will show the default apache page; while http://siteaddress/index.php will show the moodle login page; however, after login I see the apache default page again.

Any quick fix?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up Apache to use index.php as the default page.

[index.php not loading by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384423/index-php-not-loading-by-default)

Answer (score 0):

I deleted index.html, and restarted machine. It worked out -:)