# Have index.html file but still getting a directory listing

Tags: html, apache, httpd.conf, vhosts

I have an index.html file in my Apache DocumentRoot directory but when I go to my URL, I am still getting a directory listing of my DocumentRoot directory instead of the index.html file being displayed. The apache access_log shows 200's when I reload the page. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is `DirectoryIndex` set? https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex

Comment: Possible duplicate of [index.php not loading by default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384423/index-php-not-loading-by-default)

Comment: @Pekka웃 DirectoryIndex is set.

DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/ihlgt/httpdocs
DirectoryIndex /var/www/vhosts/ihlgt/httpdocs/index.html

The DocumentRoot directory which I have above is the one being listed so that seems correct to me?

Comment: You shouldn't use an absolute path. You're not telling apache the file to load. You're telling apache what filename to look for inside the Directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

It tells apache what document to show for a directory request.

**update**

You should specify just **the filename** that apache will look for in the folder requested.

Comment: Thanks! That was it. My site still isn't working. The index.html was just a test, it's really a php application I'm working on. But showing just the filename displayed the index.html and now that I've changed the DirectoryIndex to index.php, my site isn't loading. But at least I'm getting a PHP fatal error in the error log now. Finding the solution to that is another separate topic so I'll mark this answer as accepted. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Not saying this will fix it for you, but for me when first getting started with Apache2 it was file permissions that would get forgotten when moving or writing new file under the web root directory

```
ls -hal /var/www/host_one/index.html
```

If above doesn't have read (r) permissions for the same user:group or if the ownership doesn't include the user/group of the web server, then try the following for allowing group reads

```
# Modify ownership, change 'www_host' to Apache2 group
chown ${USER}:www_host /var/www/host_one/index.html
# give read+write (6) to user and read (4) to group owners
chmod 640 /var/www/host_one/index.html
```

Try refreshing the website and see if permissions where the issue. Note most web documents only require read permissions and ownership to be correct for browsers to be allowed to pick them up for rendering, on rare occasions you may need executable (1 or x) permissions for server scripts (be cautious of ownership in such cases) and last write permissions (2 or w) should likely never be seen without good reasons on files within your web root.

Second thing to try, use the index.html within your browsers URL bar

```
# by IP
http://192.168.0.100/index.html
# by domain
http://site-name.local/index.html
```

If the above loaded your document then, like @Pekka 웃 stated already, you've likely got a server option that's missing or enabling directory listings instead of looking for a index page within that directory. If this is the problem then there's two ways of *fixing* it that I've tried in the past. One, htaccess configuration to disable directory listing within that sub-directory, two, server vhost configuration to prevent whole site from directory listings. Personally I prefer to use option two and then on directories that should be allowed to be listed place an htaccess config for permissions instead of denials.