# index.php is not loading by default in apache2

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I just installed Ubuntu 17.04 and set up my LAMP server w/ PHP7 and the PHP modules enabled for Apache2.

When I go to `http://localhost/` it defaults to the `index.html` that is present in `/var/www/html` and not the `index.php` that is there. When I go to `http://localhost/index.php` the php file loads just fine and the php script executes.

In looking at other posts ( [index.php not loading by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384423/index-php-not-loading-by-default) ) I saw that the preferred solution is to edit the `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf` file to move the `index.php` before the `index.html` in the DirectoryIndex entry.

```
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml index.htm
</IfModule>
```

So I did this and saved the file as sudo, restarted the apache service as well as tried restarting the computer and it still serves the index.html first. Any idea? Should I use the .htaccess file solution instead? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have both an `index.html` and a `index.php` file? Can't you just delete `index.html`, which would cause localhost to load `index.php` by default? Also, you need to specify `DirectoryIndex` for **each** file that you wish to load. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/26700170/2341603. In fact, if you just specify the PHP file as a directory index, having the `.html` file won't matter, as Apache will load the PHP file anyway.

Comment: Can you try adding 'AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html' in your https.conf file in your apache

Comment: Hey @ObsidianAge thanks for the reply. I think it was a caching issue as mentioned below because now it's working fine. The DirectoryIndex line was like that out of the box and a help area mentioned which to load. The only reason I can imagine deleting it altogether being an issue is if I have multiple directories and if I have some that are plain old `index.html` in the subdirectories won't they not load by default if I eliminate it altogether?

Comment: you should change your title; I can see that using a "y" instead of a "t" for *"index.php not loading by default"* in your title prevented you from using that. One changed to a more descriptive title. What you have now, won't help in any search; be it Stack or Google

Comment: This is the Q&A that would have most likely solved this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640109/how-to-prevent-browser-cache-for-php-site - where "prevent browser cache" would have shown you that result in Google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is likely a caching issue in your browser when you go to `http://localhost/` try pressing `Ctrl` + `F5`

Comment: Ah that did it! Oof. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah @FrostedCookies but then you'd have to do that each time including others visiting your site should it go live. I don't think this is a concrete solution.

Comment: Ha ha, this took me a while. Damned cache!