# apache directory listing instead of executing website

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu

I installed lamp server on my Ubuntu 16.04 with these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

and then added the PHPMyAdmin via basic `apt-get` command.

My `directory root` is at `/var/www/html`.

I created simple PHP file in `http://localhost/info.php` and `http://localhost/info/info.php` containing `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` to see if PHP works and it does.

Now when I try to open my Laravel or Nette websites, located in `http://localhost/test/` and `http://localhost/fri/` I get directory listing instead of website execution.[image]

I thought this is caused by .htaccess file since Nette project has it, but Laravel project doesn't have it and behaves the same.

`apache2.conf` contains this:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/>
    Options +FollowSymLinks    
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [index.php not loading by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384423/index-php-not-loading-by-default)

Comment: http://localhost/test/ works and loads index.php just fine.

Comment: AFAIK you don't have to keep Laravel projects in `/var/www/html` directory. Simply run `php artisan serve` command in command line and it'll run localhost:8000. For more see [this](https://gist.github.com/hootlex/da59b91c628a6688ceb1) gist.

Comment: I know about Laravel php artisan, it works fine, but I want to be able to run also any other website the "classic" way.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you don't have the PHP enabled as module.

Check the folder `mods-enabled` in the Apache directory (default: /etc/apache2/) to see if you find a file named `php`.

You can tail -f in: `var/log/apache2/error.log` to see if you have errors.

If no, you can add to `apache2.conf` this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.pl index.cgi
```

If none of this works, find `DirectoryIndex` in your apache config files (probably in the `httpd.conf`), and check whether `index.php` is there (it should be there).

Hope it helps!

Comment: PHP module is enabled. mods-enabled folder contains php7.0.conf and php7.0.load files. Also there is no error.log file.

Comment: As above you need to ensure index.php comes before index.html in apache2.conf, by default .html is first. Also in both those directory listings I can't see an index.php file, which is probably why you are getting the directory listing. Try going to 'www' or 'public' and see if it loads.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.conf`

```
<Directory /var/www/html/zhyfin/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

`sudo service apache2 reload`