# Lucee Not Serving index.cfm By Default

Tags: macos, apache, tomcat, osx-elcapitan, lucee

I have a dev machine running Lucee with Tomcat on Mac OS X El Capitan. Lucee is running fine, but when I bring up my dev site, mapped to admin.local, I have to type in "admin.local:8080/index.cfm". For some reason entering the URL as "admin.local:8080" just brings up a 404. Is there something I need to do to get Lucee/Tomcat to serve index.cfm by default?

**UPDATE:**
The web.xml for Tomcat does include the following:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>CFMLServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.cfc</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>*.cfm</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>*.cfml</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>/index.cfc/*</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>/index.cfm/*</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>/index.cfml/*</url-pattern>

  <!-- url-pattern>*.cfm/*</url-pattern !-->
  <!-- url-pattern>*.cfml/*</url-pattern !-->
  <!-- url-pattern>*.cfc/*</url-pattern !-->
  <!-- url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern !-->
  <!-- url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern !-->
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Under your web server did you add index.cfm to the default document types?

Comment: Please see the update above

Comment: That is the configuration for Tomcat, which is good, but you also need to define the default document for your web server - Apache. Assuming you are requesting the page from your web server and not directly from Tomcat.

Comment: Yes, that was it. If you put it in the form of an answer, I will mark it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for your web server to handle the `index.cfm` files without specifying it in the URL you will need to add that as a default document for your web server. You mentioned you are using Apache, one approach for that web server is to add `index.cfm` to the `DirectoryIndex` within the `httpd.conf` file.

Here is an example of how to do that - https://stackoverflow.com/a/7977774/1636917

Comment: I also added the VirtualHosts but I'm not sure if I needed to do that

Answer (score 1):

I just added index.cfm to welcome file list in web.xml,  it helps

```
   <web-app ...
     
       <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>index.cfm</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
    
    </web-app>
```