# ColdFusion CommandBox - Forbidden message

Tags: coldfusion, lucee, commandbox

I have a question related to CommandBox setup. I use latest version of ColdFusion and my folder structure looks like this:

`D:/CommandBox/wwwroot`

Inside of the `wwwroot` folder I created `index.cfm` file. That file contains only one line of code:

`<cfoutput>#now()#</cfoutput>`

Once I run this in my browser this is the url I use:

`http://127.0.0.1:8080/`

The result output is the error message that I see in the browser:

`Forbidden`

If I use this url code will produce the correct output:

`http://127.0.0.1:8080/index.cfm`

I would like to know why `index.cfm` has to be included in url? Is there a way to set `index.cfm` to be default landing page? Also, I found in my root folder `C:\Users\myusername\.CommandBox\server\D9F80673BC7799BE959B513656FE8F55-CommandBox\lucee-5.3.6.61\WEB-INF` file `web.xml` that contains this code:

```
<!-- default file to execute if directory is called with no file name, e.g. http://yourip.com/ !-->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.cfm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.lucee</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
```

As you can see per comment above the code this should be default landing page. If anyone knows the reason and solution for this issue please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Which web server are you using? The default document needs to be set for your web server to handle.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lucee Not Serving index.cfm By Default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44699532/lucee-not-serving-index-cfm-by-default)

Comment: @Miguel-F That's exactly what I was looking for. The issue was that `index.cfm` didn't exist in my root folder. I added `index.cfm`, but that didn't solve the problem. At that time CommandBox was running. After I stopped CommandBox and then start again the problem was solved. If I enter 127.0.0.1:8080 the `index.cfm` content was displayed in the browser. Thank you.

Comment: Glad that helped.

Comment: You should write that up as the solution so that the next person will have an anwser. I also note that it is different than the existing Lucee solution.

Comment: @JamesAMohler I will do that. Thank you.

Comment: Did something change in your CommandBox setup? I thought CB handled `index.cfm` correctly by default. Is your server root pointing to that folder? For future readers, `FORBIDDEN` is a somewhat specific HTTP error, pretty much meaning `"I heard you and understood, but not gonna let you do it."` Essentially, a permissions thing. On our webservers, we've locked down to return `403: Forbidden` for naked url requests (no file, just domain). If the file didn't exist, I believe you would have got a `404: Not Found`. CommandBox must do some magic to reset that default document if the file's found.

Comment: @Shawn I didn't change anything in my CommanBox setup. All I did was creating `index.cfm` in my `wwwroot` folder. After the CommandBox reboot the url was loading `index.cfm` file by default.

Comment: @espresso_coffee Interesting. Might be a question worth posting to Ortus or on the Slack. The `FORBIDDEN` error that got passed back is different than what I would expect for a missing file, but makes sense if the webserver doesn't know how to interpret naked urls. Regardless, glad you got it fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution that I found for the issue above was next.

```
 1. First step in this process is to create index.cfm file inside your
    root folder (CommandBox/wwwroot)
    
 2. Stop the CommandBox
    
 3. Start CommandBox again
    
 4. Entered this url in your browser: 127.0.0.1:8080 (you can replace 8080 with your port number)
```

Answer (score 0):

There has to be `index.html` or `index.cfm` file in root folder, make sure you are not missing both.