# Joomla! site needs index.php in URL to work after AWS migration

Tags: amazon-web-services, joomla

Just migrated a site over to AWS....

Now if I try to access the site,the Joomla! Default domain page is shown rather than the site it self.

To get it to work I need to add index.php onto the end of the URL.

I've already tried switching on URL rewriting to no avail...

Any clues ?

Comment: Try removing your .htaccess file and see if the problem persists.  What is the URL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [index.php not loading by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384423/index-php-not-loading-by-default)