# Apache is not redirecting to index.php in Arch Linux

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, archlinux

I am trying to configure a Wordpress project on my localhost, but when I open the browser on `localhost` I only see the files in the root of my wordpress project.

If I click on `index.php` or access `localhost/index.php` it executes the PHP as expected.

I have installed `apache 2.4`, `php 7.2` and `php-apache 7.2`.

My project is in `/srv/http/mysite`:

The relevant lines in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

> Note: Since httpd.conf is very big I showed only the lines I know to be relevant. If this is not enough I can upload the entire file on pastebin.

The file `/etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@test.localhost
    DocumentRoot "/srv/http/mysite/"
    ServerName test.localhost
    ServerAlias test.localhost
    ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/test.localhost-error_log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/test.localhost-access_log" common

    <Directory "/srv/http/mysite/">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The file `/srv/http/mysite/.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

My `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   mycomputer_name
127.0.2.1   test.localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

About this last file I noticed that if I remove the `<IfModule ...>` and `</IfModule>` site it works and redirects to `index.php`, but I would prefer not to change this file since it works the way it is on the remote server that uses `ubuntu`.

The main question is why this is not working but I would be also happy to know what the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` is doing and why it is being ignored even though `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` is enabled.

I know this is not an easy question but I have not found anyone with this same problem on the web. I will be very grateful for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [index.php not loading by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384423/index-php-not-loading-by-default)

Comment: I have trouble finding this answer you mention, because problems with Apache on Arch Linux are usually different from what you would see in other distros. So, I would argue that keeping this question would be beneficial for Arch Linux users, but I am not an expert on stackoverflow rules, I will agree with your decision if you think this should be deleted. But it is likely that the answer you mention won't be spotted by other Arch users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apache needs to be setup to recognize your index files (in this case index.php)

Do you have the following in your Directory

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

So

```
<Directory "/srv/http/mysite/">
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

In httpd.conf you should have something like...

```
<IfModule dir_module> 
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.htm index.html
</IfModule>
```

This would be your catch-all fall-back.

And then in your httpd-vhosts.conf one of many site descriptions might look something like...

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin admin@siteName.com
    DocumentRoot "e:/Stack/Sites/siteName/web"
    ServerName siteName
    ServerAlias siteNameUser
    <Directory "e:/Stack/Sites/SiteName/web">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "logs/siteName.error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/siteName.access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Note: The `DirectoryIndex index.php` in httpd-vhosts.conf site declaration is unnecessary if you included the fall-back defaults in httpd.conf

If you are not wanting to use default port 80 then in either file have something like:  `Listen 8080`

For localhost I use: in httpd.conf... `Listen 127.0.0.1:8080` and in httpd-vhosts.conf `Listen 8080`

In your hosts file you will need to define something like...
127.0.0.1       siteName siteNameUser www.siteName.com

Currently using: Apache/2.4.33 (Win64) PHP/7.2.4 ~ MySql 5.7.22 homebrew stack.
The httpd-vhosts.conf example portion is for Drupal 8.x - For WP your DocumentRoot and Directory will differ.

You can listen on multiple ports such as 8080 for dev, 8081 for test, 8082 for prod. Also you can have many different site definitions in your httpd-vhosts.conf file.

I prefer to define all sites in httpd-vhosts.conf, but you could just place them in httpd.conf