# Send user to .com/index.php when calling ".com/" or ".com"

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to send a user to "/index.php" when they don't specify a file in the URL.

This is probably a really simple fix because I know it's a common problem, and I've tried multiple answers on SO, though they didn't work.

Here's what some examples of what I've tried

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php

OR

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [NC,L,QSA]

OR

DirectoryIndex index.php
```

This is the rest of the htaccess file which I need to whitelist a few files that should be open, everything else should not be accessed.

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
<FilesMatch "index\.php|logout\.php|login\.php|main\.css|logo2\.png|bg\.jpg|logoAuth\.png|favicon\.ico|grafikk_venstreNede\.png|grafikk_hoyreMidt\.png">
  Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Expected result is calling "domain.com" and the server responds with "domain.com/index.php"

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [index.php not loading by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384423/index-php-not-loading-by-default)

Comment: Adding `DirectoryIndex index.php` to before or after the other code part doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try with httpd.conf?

Comment: No, I tried .htaccess as it said in the correct answer.

Comment: Well, try the other ones too

Comment: The other ones I put in the post? I've already tried all of them, before and after the FilesMatch part.

Comment: I mean the other answers to the linked question.

Comment: Perhaps you need `Option Indexes`, too, in the directory section of the web server configuration.

Comment: Where would I add this @OleWolf ? .htaccess or httpd.conf?

Comment: That would be in the <Directory ...> blocks in the site configuration files. Depending on your distribution, they're typically in /etc/apache2/sites-available.

Answer (score 0):

Set `DirectoryIndex index.php` in either your apache config file or in the .htaccess file.

Comment: Adding it to before or after the other code part doesn't work.

Comment: just to be clear, this 

```DirectoryIndex index.php

Order deny,allow
Deny from all
<FilesMatch "index\.php|logout\.php|login\.php|main\.css|logo2\.png|bg\.jpg|logoAuth\.png|favicon\.ico|grafikk_venstreNede\.png|grafikk_hoyreMidt\.png">
  Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```
doesn't work, you would just get "Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server."